# Intermittent 404 error in java multithreading when threads are calling external service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am working on multithreading for the first time and I have used thread pool.

```
private CartResponse executeWithinThreadPool(List<CartSaveMultithreadWorker> workers,
        CartResponse CartResponse) throws CartException {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(mapperServiceThreads < 0 ? workers.size()
            : mapperServiceThreads);

    List<Future<CartResponse>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CartSaveMultithreadWorker w : workers) {
        Future<CartResponse> future = executor.submit(w);
        futureList.add(future);
    }
    try {
        executor.shutdown();
        boolean workersCompleted = executor.awaitTermination((workers.size() * threadTimeout), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (workersCompleted) {
            LOGGER.info("Executor completed correctly");
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Executor did not complete successfully");
        }
        boolean isFailed = false;
        for (Future<CartResponse> future : futureList) {
            CartResponse CartResponse1 = future.get();
            if (CartResponse1 != null
                    && CartResponse1.getResponseStatus() != null
                    && !"SUCESS".equalsIgnoreCase(CartResponse1.getResponseStatus().getStatus())) {
                isFailed = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        CartResponse = failureCaseResponse(CartResponse, futureList, isFailed);
    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        LOGGER.error("Interrupted exception while executing worker threads: ", exception);
        throw new CartException();

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while executing worker threads", exception);
        throw new CartException();

    } finally {
        if ((!executor.isTerminated()) || (!executor.isShutdown())) {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    }
    return CartResponse;

}
```

and my `mapperServiceThreads=3 and timeout=25000`.

This is being called from

```
for (String item: CartRequest.getItemNumber()) {
                workers.add(new CartSaveMultithreadWorker(cartDao,
                        cartRequest, itemNumber));
            }
...
...
cartResponse1= executeWithinThreadPool(workers, cartResponse);
```

This throws intermittent error for saving the cart to my SOR when there is even 6 items in the cart. ANy idea why ?

Comment: What error does it throw?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the rate limit of the service being called from code. On fixing the rate limit, it started working.